# IntelliJ live template for logging a selected variable in js

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15, live-templates

I would like to add a new line right after the line where I selected a variable name. This line should than contain the selection.

Example:

```
var variable = getValue();
```

I select the word "variable", press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to apply a live template or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to surround the selection with a live template and get something like this:

```
var value = getValue();
console.log('[value]', value);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This doesn't work exactly as you expect, but the result is the same. Create a new Live Template (Settings → Editor → Live Templates) and add an abbreviation (e.g. `logv`). Set the applicable context to `Javascript`. Use this as a template:

```
console.log("$EXPR_COPY$ = " + $EXPR$);
```

Now click the `Edit variables` button and copy this:

[image]

The order is important: first `EXPR`, then `EXPR_COPY`.

Now you can type `logv` (the abbreviation you chose) to paste the template. You will have to enter the variable name (using autocompletion), but the variable name will be copied into the string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I had to enter the variable name twice, your idea is better than what I had.